# Using OR as query parser parameter unnecessary document are returned for long queries

Tags: solr

When I tried to get result for long query then large number of documents that contains only part of query string are returned. I have been using OR as default Operator in schema. What should i do in order to make document order in the order of the score or documents that matches the query more than only its words.

Comment: I have a hard time parsing your question and what you're actually asking for - could you expand with a few examples and what your desired behaviour is?

Comment: While searching for long query in solr like "seven wonders of world" the resulting documents are too large since the documents that contains "seven" only , "wonders" only, "world " only are also returned.My aim is to parse query such that it only return relevent documents only rather than large number of unnecessary documents.In fact, i want relevency tuning of query.

Comment: Have you looked at either `q.op` or [`mm`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm(MinimumShouldMatch)Parameter) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at tools like [Splainer](http://splainer.io/) for some relevancy explanations.

In general, you need to spend a bit of time living in the debug output as that will tell you exactly what's going on.

By default, unless you give an explicit sort parameter, Solr will sort by relevancy. And it will try to match as many keywords as possible. So it should be working already.

If it does not, something else is not on that simple path and you need to add additional parameter to make it work. If you want to reduce the items matched all together, look at **mm** parameter as MatsLindh says. If you are ok with number matched but the order is not right, perhaps you are searching across multiple fields with eDisMax and could benefit from non-zero **tie** parameter.